# Python - Hierarchical clustering with starting weights

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

I'm trying to perform hierarchical/agglomerative clustering using Ward's method on "pre-clustered" clusters. Since these inputs may not have the same cardinality, the updated distances using scipy's linkage function will be skewed.

To be clear, I have `n` input clusters, a compressed distance matrix with `n*(n-1)/2` values (the same given from pdist), and weights corresponding to each of the input clusters. What package should I use to cluster my inputs? Or is there a way to manipulate my input to work with scipy?

(Note: I've seen this with R's `hclust` function where you can specify the `members` weights initially, would like something similar with Python)

Comment: It would make it easier to help if you provided some input data one can just copy and paste.